# Make Ant's Java task print empty lines

Tags: java, ant

When running Java applications through the [java Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) empty lines are not printed. This makes it harder scan long output files, since all separation is removed.

Do anybody know how to make ant print empty lines?

Thanks

**Example:**

Running the following java code through ant:

```
System.out.println("Hello");
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("World");
```

I expect ant to produce:

```
[java] Hello
[java]  
[java] World
```

But the outputs is

```
[java] Hello
[java] World
```

Comment: Since it's just for formatting purposes, can you use " " (a space) instead?  This will make Ant print a blank line and it won't appear any different when running outside of Ant.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following code using Ant 1.8.2 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 as well as on Windows 7. On both operating systems the empty line was printed as shown in the output below.

### JavaTest.java

```java
/**
 * Java test.
 */
public class JavaTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("World");
  }
}
```

### Inside build.xml

```
<target name="java-test" depends="compile">
  <java classpath="${classes.dir}" classname="JavaTest"
      fork="true" failonerror="true" />
</target>
```

### Output

```
$ ant java-test 
Buildfile: /home/my/project/build.xml

java-test:
     [java] Hello
     [java] 
     [java] World

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way without compiling special classes - use script e.g.

```
<script language="groovy">
       println("Hello\n\nWorld!")
</script>
```